# How does .NET create and execute its Windows, buttons, etc.?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been wondering from the first day, when I started to read, how does the .NET Framework work?

First it's really good to have an IDE like Visual Studio. While for example when I click and drop the textboxes, buttons, set their properties and so on, everything works fine. 
But in the case of Java in most cases we as a programmers write coding to develop a Frame (window). But in case of .NET, Visual Studio make things easier, but how does work that, without writing a single line of code, all Windows, buttons, etc. are created?

And if I change the button name in the Form design area, where does this get stored, and more importantly how does it get displayed when we execute our program? Is this magic? Or there is a long process under the hood?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is absolutely no magic behind this. The visual forms designer in Visual Studio generates C# code for you. Just chceck the `Form1.designer.cs` file.

Comment: oh ok fine :) then in case we write code in notepad and write means , we have to manually create this File??

Comment: No, this file is not even required for a C# Winforms program to work. The Form.designer.cs file declares a partial class, which means that the code is mixed together with your own code in Form.cs. You can as well write your whole Winforms Forms app in notepad and compile it as a single .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your .designer.cs is generated by serialization (objects -> code, code -> objects). Look at the CodeDomSerializer class if you wanna try understand better what is happening under the hood (with Reflector you might wanna check ControlCodeDomSerializer in System.Design.dll). And of course you can create your own serializer for custom controls and components.